# Rails Admin HABTM Association in Views not showing select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am customizing RailsAdmin for one of my project. I am trying to achieve multi select box like below for many to many association

[image]

My Class are different (No Teams) , I have tour and programs

**Tour Class**

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :programs
end
```

**Program Class**

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tours
end
```

**Joint Table**

```
class ProgramsTours < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change 
    create_table :programs_tours, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :program_id
      t.integer :tour_id
    end
  end
end
```

This association creating an Multiple Add form with tabs as below , I am not sure how I can get that multi select box, any suggestions will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: have a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes or the revised version at http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised (if you have a pro account)

Comment: Tux , thanks for fast reply. I know about collection and select boxes. But I don't know how to get two way select box like shown in above screen shot in railsAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessible :name, :program_ids

   has_and_belongs_to_many :programs

end


class Program < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessible :name, :tour_ids

   has_and_belongs_to_many :tours

end
```